# Maximum Value of the Square of Distances between Two Points in the Unit Sphere

Tags: geometry, vectors

15 points $P_i$ are placed within the unit sphere. Find the maximum possible value of $$\sum_{1\leq i \lt j \leq 15} \vert P_i P_j\vert^2$$ 
given that $x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2 \leq 1$

I saw this problem on a mathematics website and I was curious about this. Can you please provide me some books that may enlighten me about this topic? I think the problem asks to find the square of the lengths of line segments connecting $P_1$ to $P_2$, $P_2$ to $P_3$, $P_3$ to $P_4$ and so on (except $P_{15}$ to $P_1$?)
I tried to solve this using a little knowledge about properties of vectors$$A.A = \vert A \vert^2$$ hence the distance between the vector connecting the two points is $$\vert P_j - P_i\vert$$ and $$\sum_{1\leq i \lt j \leq 15} \vert P_j - P_i\vert^2 =\sum_{1\leq i \lt j \leq 15} (P_j-P_i).(P_j-P_i) = \sum_{1\leq i \lt j \leq 15} P_j^2-2P_j.P_i+P_i^2$$ I don't know how to solve the last expression so I got stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\sum\limits_{1 \le i < j \le 15}|P_i-P_j|^2$ isn't a sum over 
the $14$ line segments $P_1 \to P_2 \to \cdots \to P_{15}$. 
It is a sum over
the $105 = \frac{15 \times 14}{2}$ pair of points. Notice 
$$\begin{align} \sum_{1 \le i<j \le 15} |P_i-P_j|^2 
&= \frac12 \sum_{1 \le i, j \le 15}|P_i - P_j|^2
= \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^{15}\sum_{j=1}^{15} (|P_i|^2 + |P_j|^2 - 2 P_i \cdot P_j )\\
&= 15 \sum_{j=1}^{15} |P_j|^2 - \left|\sum_{j=1}^{15}P_j\right|^2 \\
&\le 15 \sum_{j=1}^{15} |P_j|^2 \le 225
\end{align}
$$
The maximum value of this sum is at most $225$. It is easy to find a configuration of $15$ points such that all $|P_j| = 1$ and  $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{15} P_j = 0$ (e.g. a regular pentadecagon lying on the equator). For such a configuration, the value $225$ is achieved. This means the maximum value we seek is indeed $225$.

For the sum over the $14$ line segments, the maximum is $56 = 14\times 2^2$ and this value is achieved when we place the points alternatively over a pair of anti-podal points (e.g. $P_1 = P_3 = \cdots P_{15} = (0,0,1)$ and $P_2 = P_4 = \cdots = P_{14} = (0,0,-1)$).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, need some enlightenment for this. Can you suggest me some books discussing problems similar to this?

Comment: I'm not aware of books that discuss problems similar to this. This sort of problems seem to be out of favor in past 50 years. You can look at books from Dover who have reprinted a lot of classics from last century.

Comment: what does $\sum_{i\le i,j \le 15}$ mean. Really sorry, another problem is I don't know how to evaluate such sums.

Comment: It means sum over the 225 combination of $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i \le 15$ and $1 \le j \le 15$.

Comment: The first summation tells to sum the squares of distances between any two points, and the second means to half the sum the squares of distances from a relative point (do this to all 15 points) to the other points. How is this so? Is it an identity?

Comment: Let $f_{ij} = |P_i-P_j|^2$, notice $f_{ij} = f_{ji}$ and $f_{ii} = 0$. So $$\sum\limits_{i<j} f_{ij} = \sum\limits_{i>j} f_{ij} = \frac12 \left( \sum\limits_{i<j} f_{ij} + \sum\limits_{i>j} f_{ij} + \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=j} f_{ij}}_{=0}\right) = \frac12 \sum\limits_{i,j} f_{ij}$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back to this later.